# pymongo altering dict object makes pymongocursor empty

Tags: python, flask, pymongo, python-3.4

I am using Flask-0.11, Flask-PyMongo-0.4.1 and python 3.4.3. 
I use this way, I can get the objects from iterator here.

```
query = {"user_name":"sathis"}
element = self.collection.find(query).limit(10).sort("created_date",-1)
for ele in element:
     print(ele)
```

But when I perform some dict operation, I didn't find any data in cursor

```
query = {"user_name":"sathis"}
element = self.collection.find(query).limit(10).sort("created_date,-1")
query['_id'] = {"$lt": "59bd1e01078dc56e82084de6"}
for ele in element:
    print(ele)
```

Help me with your suggestions.

Comment: Its just typo. @Nabin

Comment: I didn't get you

Comment: `element = self.collection.find(dict(query)).limit(10).sort("created_date":-1)` this also working fine.

Comment: Please post the outputs as well. The full output

Comment: Initially your question was about passing dictionary in find method. Now it has completely changed

Comment: What is this __query['_id'] = {"$lt": "59bd1e01078dc56e82084de6"}__ ?

Comment: adding another key value in query dict

Comment: Who would ever compare id? :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you cannot determine if your document id would be less than something as the id is generated randomly. Also you cannot directly do selection on your id.

```
query['_id'] = "59bd1e01078dc56e82084de6" # NOT A VALID THING TO DO
```

But

```
query['_id'] = ObjectId("59bd1e01078dc56e82084de6") # VALID
```

Comment: It just a typo i changed now